# Why can't bitbake find and install my script?

Tags: linux, environment-variables, recipe, openembedded, bitbake

I'm trying to write a simple bitbake recipe which will install some scripts into a target Root File System. I must be missing something, because I feel like I set this up correctly, but I keep getting an error message:

```
ERROR: Function failed: do_install (see /home/mike/ULF/ulf/build-ulf/out/work/armv7ahf-vfp-neon-linux-gnueabihf/ttt/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_install.493 for further information)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/mike/ULF/ulf/build-ulf/out/work/armv7ahf-vfp-neon-linux-gnueabihf/ttt/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_install.493
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_install
| install: cannot stat `uim2svc.sh': No such file or directory
| ERROR: Function failed: do_install (see /home/mike/ULF/ulf/build-ulf/out/work/armv7ahf-vfp-neon-linux-gnueabihf/ttt/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_install.493 for further information)
ERROR: Task 2 (/home/mike/ULF/ulf/oe-ghmi/recipes/images/ttt.bb, do_install) failed with exit code '1'
```

Now I've read the [bitbake documenation on the local-file-fetcher](http://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.6/bitbake-user-manual/bitbake-user-manual.html#local-file-fetcher) and it says:

> > This submodule handles URLs that begin with file://. The filename you specify with in the URL can either be an absolute or relative path to a file. If the filename is relative, the contents of the FILESPATH variable is used in the same way PATH is used to find executables.

So I have the file name in my `SRC_URI`, the script in the local `files` directory, and I've checked out the output from the build and the path points to my script directory... ***so why am I getting this error still***? Anyone have ideas on what I could be doing wrong?

---

Here's my full bitbake recipe (ttt.bb):

```
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COREBASE}/LICENSE;md5=3f40d7994397109285ec7b81fdeb3b58"
SRC_URI = "file://uim2svc.sh"

do_install() {
    install -d ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc
    install -d -m 0755 ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/init.d
    install -m 0755 uim2svc.sh ${IMAGE_ROOTFS}/etc/init.d/
}
```

And here's the tree (starting at /home/mike/ULF/ulf) showing where the files are:

```
oe-ghmi/
├── classes
├── conf
├── recipes
│   └── images
│       ├── files
│       │   └── uim2svc.sh
│       ├── global-hmi-image.bb
│       ├── ttt.bb
```

And the (truncated) output from `bitbake -e ttt`:

> > > FILESPATH="...:/home/mike/ULF/ulf/oe-ghmi/recipes/images/files/armv7a:/home/mike/ULF/ulf/oe-ghmi/recipes/images/files/ghmi:**/home/mike/ULF/ulf/oe-ghmi/recipes/images/files/**"

Answer (score 7):

According to the [OpenEmbedded manual](http://docs.openembedded.org/usermanual/usermanual.pdf), section 9.13:

```
When source code is specified as a part of SRC_URI it is unpacked into 
the work directory, ${WORKDIR}.
```

So, your script is detected by bitbake and deployed in `${WORKDIR}`. The method `do_install()`  should reference the file relative to `${WORKDIR}`.
There's an example in the manual in section *9.13.2. file: for patches and additional files*:

```
Non-patch files are copied to the work directory, ${WORKDIR}. You can access
these files from within a recipe by referring to them relative to the work
directory. The following example, from the quagga recipe, shows the above 
init script being included in the package by copying it during the install 
task
```

and the code provided shows how to do this:

```
do_install () {
# Install init script and default settings
install -m 0755 -d ${D}${sysconfdir}/default ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d ${D}${sysconfdir}/
install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/quagga.init ${D}${sysconfdir}/init.d/quagga
...
```

It's also probably worth noting that files are not copied directly to `${IMAGE_ROOTFS}`, but to ${D} instead. From section `7.4 Tasks`:

```
install
The install task is responsible for actually installing everything. 
This needs to install the software into the destination directory, D. 
This directory won’t actually be a part of the final package though. 
In other words if you install something into ${D}/bin then it will end 
up in the /bin directory in the package and therefore on the target.
```

Once finished `do_install`, directory `${D}` is packaged and then installed into the final ROOTFS directory, `${IMAGE_ROOTFS}`, by `rootfs_ipkg` class (called by the recepie for the image you are building). From section `9.10 rootfs_ipkg class`:

```
The rootf_ipk class is used to create a root filesystem for the target
device from a set of .ipkg packages.
```

Among the tasks performed:

```
4. Configures ipkg to allow it to be used locally to install into the 
root filesystem ${IMAGE_ROOTFS};
5. Installs locale related .ipkg packages;
```

From `${IMAGE_ROOTFS}` the final filesystem is eventually created.

Comment: it's also worth adding that to _be_installed_into_the_real_rootfs, package should be added to image with IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " xxx" in local.conf or in corresponding image recipy

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the below line above the ""SRC_URI " like this

## FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}:"

LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COREBASE}/LICENSE;md5=3f40d7994397109285ec7b81fdeb3b58"
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}:"
SRC_URI = "file://uim2svc.sh"

the bitbake searching the dir same name of recipe name thats why it doest copy the WORKDIR
now you are adding FILESEXTRAPATHS line then it will search from dir path of your RECIPE.